# Customizing Material-UI Components in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a boilerplate for a React Project with a customized theme using Material-UI made by Google.

I followed this Google codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-112-web/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Basically, my plan is to make customized components using the components listed here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react

However, the tutorial (codelab) shows nothing about changing the style of the component.

I need help with this. Thanks.

Comment: I agree. The new material-ui docs suck on customizing.

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly. Material-UI is not made by Google. You might find more help if you adjust the tags for this post.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is useful for someone looking for a possible solution/s. All the solutions can be found [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/) in Material UI's docu with clear examples.

I'll show you the **Global Theme Solution** with the  **component**, which will give you consistency between components, and apply global styles.

You take advantage of the `overrides` key to literally override the styles of the classes and elements injected by Material UI into the DOM. You can inspect them in the browser and see which ones you want to customise.

You have to wrap the child component inside a MuiThemeProvider and pass a createMuiTheme object to it as a theme property value.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    // overrides label color and asterisk (if input set as required)
    MuiInputLabel: {
      root: {
        color: '#001E50 !important',
        '&$focused': {
          color: '#001E50 !important'
        }
      },
      asterisk: {
        color: '#001E50 !important'
      }
    },
    // overrides input styles
    MuiInputBase: {
      root: {
        color: '#001E50 !important',
        '&$focused': {
          color: '#001E50 !important'
        }
      }
    },
    // overrides the bottom line of the input
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        '&:before': {
          borderBottom: '1px solid #DFE4E8 !important'
        },
        '&:after': {
          borderBottom: '1px solid #001E50 !important'
        },
        }
      }
    }
  },
});


export function CustomInput() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme = { theme }>
            <TextField name="name" label="Name" required/>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
})
```